# ViewPager not showing anything

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am create view pager with custom view pager adapter but when i run the project i can not see anything

```
  public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private List<NewsObject> newsObjects;
        private Activity mActivity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ImageLoaderConfiguration imageConfig;
        private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        public CustomAdapter(List<NewsObject> newsObjects, Activity mActivity) {
            super();
            Log.d("Con :", "structor");
            this.newsObjects = newsObjects;
            this.mActivity = mActivity;
            imageConfig = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                    mActivity.getApplicationContext()).build();
            imageLoader.init(imageConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.newsObjects.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            ImageViewPlus img_news_image;
            TextView txt_news_title;
            TextView txt_news_description;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_news_page, null);

            img_news_image = (ImageViewPlus) viewLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_detail_news_image);
            txt_news_title = (TextView) viewLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_detail_news_title);
            txt_news_description = (TextView) viewLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_detail_news_description);

            Log.d("TAG :", "instantiateItem");

            imageLoader.displayImage(newsObjects.get(position).getNews_image(),
                    img_news_image);

            Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                    Constantz.newsObjects.get(position).getNews_id() + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            txt_news_title.setText(newsObjects.get(position).getNews_title());
            txt_news_description.setText(newsObjects.get(position)
                    .getNews_description());

            return viewLayout;
        }

    }
```

but the toast is displaying but i can not see any text on my application

Answer (score 72, accepted):

write

```
container.addView(viewLayout);
```

before returning the view in `instantiateItem`

```
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        ImageViewPlus img_news_image;
        TextView txt_news_title;
        TextView txt_news_description;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_news_page, null);

        img_news_image = (ImageViewPlus) viewLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.img_detail_news_image);
        txt_news_title = (TextView) viewLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_detail_news_title);
        txt_news_description = (TextView) viewLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_detail_news_description);

        Log.d("TAG :", "instantiateItem");

        imageLoader.displayImage(newsObjects.get(position).getNews_image(),
                img_news_image);

        Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                Constantz.newsObjects.get(position).getNews_id() + "",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        txt_news_title.setText(newsObjects.get(position).getNews_title());
        txt_news_description.setText(newsObjects.get(position)
                .getNews_description());
        container.addView(viewLayout);

        return viewLayout;
    }
```

Comment: Not expecting this. The designer of this API has at most half brain left.

Comment: It's a very old API, can't believe I'm using it actually and nothing better appeared! But don't kid about brain missing, you have no idea what parts of the brains missing do to a person....

Comment: Thanks @vipul mittal for this answer :)

Comment: @Radu As of 2020, it's better to go with ViewPager2. You can use RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: Can u please answer my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/65439715/11567530

Answer (score 9):

You have missed to add your view to the container. Need to add before return your view.

```
((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);
```

also sure that you have set current item for View Pager.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't adding your view to the container.

```
container.addView(viewLayout, 0);
```

Comment: In my case the second argument `0` made a difference, e.g., it worked then.

Answer (score -2):

```
<TabHost
     ......
<TabWidget
.....
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp" >
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

Comment: Some explanation wouldn't hurt. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)